# How can I force the input outline to over or come above the icon box shadow

Tags: html, css, border, z-index, outline

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSey1.jpg)

- HTML

  ```
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address"  id="main-input" >
    <span id="arrow-icon"><img src="images/icon-arrow.svg" alt="arrow icon"></span>
    <span id="error-icon"><img src="images/icon-error.svg" alt="error icon"></span>
  ```
- CSS

  ```
    #main-input{
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 30px;
  z-index: 100;}
  ```

  #main-input:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  border: 2px solid hsl(0, 93%, 68%);}

  #arrow-icon{
  width: 90px;
  height: 52px;
  position: absolute;
  background:linear-gradient(to right, hsl(0, 80%, 86%) 0%, hsl(0, 74%, 74%) 100%)  ;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-left: -91px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 3px 16px 10px 0px #f4dddd;
  cursor: pointer;}
  #arrow-icon img{
  /* width: 10px;
  height: 20px; */
  margin-left: 41px;
  margin-top: 15px;}`

Answer (score 0):

- Wrap input and span are in a div tag
- add position: relative and the same height & width as input to the div tag
- remove margins to span icon tag and add right and top properties adjust them accordingly